# How to store gujarati data into mysql server?

Tags: mysql, locale

I want to execute one functionality in which i have to upload an excel sheet having data in gujarati font and after uploading i have to store that data into mysql database.

Now here i have to use two languages for displaying output - one is english and one is gujarati.

Somewhere i have to display mysql db data in english and somewhere in gujarati.

Now i need suggestion that how could i implement such functionality?

Should i change mysql server locale to gujarati or should i keep the mysql server in english locale and convert the data from gujarati to eng or eng to gujarati at frontend.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should Change the field's collation to `utf8_bin` so that MySQL will stores the data in gujarati and in english properly.

Answer (score 1):

To store Gujarati data into MySQL server, you need to make sure that the database and table are set up to support Unicode characters, and that your database connection is also set up to use UTF-8 encoding. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Create a MySQL database: Log in to your MySQL server and create a database using a command like this:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE your_database_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This creates a database named `your_database_name` with the `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, which supports Gujarati characters.

2. Create a MySQL table: Create a table in your database that contains the fields you need to store Gujarati data. For example, you can use a command like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  address VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
);
```

This creates a table named `your_table_name` with an id field and two fields to store Gujarati data: `name` and `address`. The `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` part of the command specifies that the `name` and `address` fields should use the `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

3. Insert Gujarati data into the table: To insert Gujarati data into the table, you can use a command like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table_name (name, address) VALUES ('ગુજરાતી નામ', 'ગુજરાતી સરનામું');
```

This inserts a row into the `your_table_name` table with the Gujarati `name` and `address`.

Make sure that your database connection is also set up to use UTF-8 encoding. In PHP, you can set the connection character set to `utf8mb4` using a command like this:

```bash
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8mb4");
```

Replace `$connection` with your database connection object. This ensures that the data is properly encoded when it is sent to and retrieved from the MySQL server.

Answer (score -1):

Into your connection file you want to include a line of code:

```
mysql_query('set names utf8');
```